# My table header resizes when setting table body to block to only make that part scrollable, how do I prevent that?

Tags: html, css

So, I tried creating a table in which only the body is scrollable, but can't seem to fix this issue. The table header should be as wide as the table body of course.. What am I doing wrong?

[image: This is the visual result]
**The visual result**

This is my HTML and CSS for the table:
(NOTE: I insert the table rows via JS)

```
<table class="metadata_table">
<thead class="thead">
    <tr class="tr">
        <th class="th" scope="col">Tag</th>
        <th class="th" scope="col">Creator</th>
        <th class="th" scope="col">Source</th>
        <th class="th" scope="col">Date of creation</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="table-body">
</tbody>
```

```
.metadata_table {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 120px;
    max-height: 105px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 35px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    display: none;
    float: top;
    width: fit-content;
}

thead tr:first-child {
    background: #39ae3f;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
}

.th, .td {
    padding: 0 15px 0 20px;
}

.th {
    font-weight: 500;
}

thead .tr:last-child .th {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
}

tbody .tr:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    cursor: default;
}

tbody .td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.table-body {
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 105px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.td:last-child {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `width: 100%;` to `.thead`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set static widths, perhaps in EMs, or use JavaScript to set the widths:

```
function setHeaderCellWidths() {
    var aSlice=Array.prototype.slice;
    aSlice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.metadata_table')).forEach(function(table){
        var tds=table.querySelectorAll('tbody:first-of-type tr:first-child>*');
        aSlice.call(table.querySelectorAll('thead th')).forEach(function(cell,idx){
            cell.style.width=window.getComputedStyle(tds[idx],null).width;
        });
    });
}
window.addEventListener('load',setHeaderCellWidths,null);
window.addEventListener('resize',function(){
    clearTimeout(setHeaderCellWidths.timer);
    setHeaderCellWidths.timer=setTimeout(setHeaderCellWidths,250);
},null);
```